# Pandas: how to correct values less than the previous and some patterns

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have the following time series:

`2017-11-01   200.000000
2017-12-01   394.000000
2018-01-01   537.000000
2018-02-01   537.000000
2018-03-01   537.000000
2018-04-01   537.000000
2018-05-01   537.000000
2018-06-01   537.000000
2018-07-01   137.000000
2018-08-01   88.000000
2018-09-01   10.000000
2018-10-01   100.000000
2018-11-01   100.000000
2018-12-01   111.000000
2019-01-01   362.000000
2019-02-01   563.000000
2019-03-01   706.000000
2019-04-01   750.000000
2019-05-01   785.000000
2019-06-01   785.000000`

I am dealing with a periodic time series, where the values are cumulative from September to August.
In September the value should be lower than the previous. This is not true for previous months!
So, my time series is wrong 2018-07-01 and 2018-08-01, but it's right in 2018-09-01.
I want to substitute those values with the last one in 2018-06-01 (537.0).

I used the .shift(1) pandas option, but I have been able only to substitute July's values with June's, but I replaced August with the previous value of July! Here the code I used:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': new_df.index.tolist(), 'vals': new_df.tolist()}) # from df to ts
new_df['shift_values'] = new_df['vals'].shift(1) # create a col with previous values
new_df['diff'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: x['vals']-x['shift_values'], axis=1) # calculate the difference
new_df['valore_finale'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: x['vals'] if x['date'] == '2019-09-01' else(x['vals'] if x['diff']>0 else x['shift_values']), axis=1)
```

`2017-11-01   200.000000
2017-12-01   394.000000
2018-01-01   537.000000
2018-02-01   537.000000
2018-03-01   537.000000
2018-04-01   537.000000
2018-05-01   537.000000
2018-06-01   537.000000
2018-07-01   537.000000 # changed
2018-08-01   537.000000 # changed
2018-09-01   10.000000 # no changed
2018-10-01   100.000000
2018-11-01   100.000000
2018-12-01   111.000000
2019-01-01   362.000000
2019-02-01   563.000000
2019-03-01   706.000000
2019-04-01   750.000000
2019-05-01   785.000000
2019-06-01   785.000000`

Comment: Yes.........that's what I want, to correct them....

Comment: please show your expected dataframe

Comment: @ansev I added the expected dataframe

Comment: What happens if in January the value is lower than in December of the previous year?

Answer (score 0):

first convert to datetime to be able to use `mask` based on the months you want to modify:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then use [Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to put as `NaN` 
the values ​​you want to change and then fill with[Series.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
df['vals']=df['vals'].mask((df['date'].dt.month<9) & (df['vals']<df['vals'].shift())).ffill()
print(df)
         date   vals
0  2017-11-01  200.0
1  2017-12-01  394.0
2  2018-01-01  537.0
3  2018-02-01  537.0
4  2018-03-01  537.0
5  2018-04-01  537.0
6  2018-05-01  537.0
7  2018-06-01  537.0
8  2018-07-01  537.0
9  2018-08-01  537.0
10 2018-09-01   10.0
11 2018-10-01  100.0
12 2018-11-01  100.0
13 2018-12-01  111.0
14 2019-01-01  362.0
15 2019-02-01  563.0
16 2019-03-01  706.0
17 2019-04-01  750.0
18 2019-05-01  785.0
19 2019-06-01  785.0
```

**if for January the value of December of the previous year must not be taken into account, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) must be used.**

```
g=df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)['vals']
df['vals']=df['vals'].mask( (df['vals']<g.shift())&(df['date'].dt.month<9) ).ffill()
```

---

**Details**

[Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) is used to to make the comparison with the previous one.

[datetime.dt.month](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) is used to get months before september

Comment: It works for my example. I want something more automatic. I already tried with ffill in that way. The problem is when I deal with multiple years. I should gather all the dates in September.

Comment: check my new solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is very greedy, but works!

```
results = [new_df.vals[0]]
new_value = 0

for index, values in new_df[1:].iterrows():
    if '09' not in str(values.date):  # if date is not September
        if values.vals < new_value:
            new_value = new_value
        else:
            new_value = values.vals
    else:
        new_value = values.vals
    results.append(new_value)

new_df['new_values'] = [r for r in results]
```

Hope someone will be able to find something better using pandas.

Comment: check my solution